# What's causing Adobe Flash Player Update Service to fault?

Tags: windows-xp, flash-player

I have a user that started receiving the following error message pulling it from the event log:

> Faulting application FlashPlayerUpdateService.exe, version
>   11.3.300.265, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 5.1.2600.6055, fault address 0x000113b5.

This is very strange because there were no issues known issues previously.  I've tried uninstalling a reinstalling and can't figure out what's causing.  The error displays serveral times in a day.  For now, I've disabled the service.  **Anybody come across this?**

Comment: Have you been able to replicate the conditions that cause the error to happen?

Comment: I don't know how to replicate it.  I do however, have 3 machines that is encountering this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to Adobe's page for this bug: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3225162.

The bug has since been resolved, so if you're still having this problem, just update Flash Player.